# UpperCase convert from Input Tag to a method in component

Tags: angular, methods, components, uppercase

This code is at the moment in the <input tag

How could i make this code in to a method in my component?

```
oninput="let p=this.selectionStart; this.value=this.value.toUpperCase(); this.setSelectionRange(p, p);"
```

Comment: I'll bite... cut and paste the code into the backing *.ts* code file where a function is defined? Then change the code above to call that function? Am I right? :|

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use `this.variableName` in html you should just write `variableName`. Second;

`<ng-container *ngFor="let p = selectionStart"> .....(oninput)="functionName(p,p)" </ng-container>`

if you're not using a ngFor Loop outside this code and selectionStart is just a variable you can use `functionName(selectionStart, selectionStart)`

might do the work.